# How to do Client side routing using react router 1.0.x in a click handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a Single Page App. I can use the client side router using `<Link>` tags provided by react-router.
`<Link to='/nextRoute'>next</Link`
 But what if I need to change the route from a click handler? (I've got some things to do before navigating away)

Using `window.location.assign` will result in the whole thing being fetched from server again but i need to use the client side router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe 1.0.x used the [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package.

You'd have to check which version of history you're using, but from the docs there is:

```
// Push a new entry onto the history stack.
history.push('/home')

// Replace the current entry on the history stack.
history.replace('/profile')

// Push a new entry with state onto the history stack.
history.push({
  pathname: '/about',
  search: '?the=search',
  state: { some: 'state' }
})

// Change just the search on an existing location.
history.push({ ...location, search: '?the=other+search' })

// Go back to the previous history entry. The following
// two lines are synonymous.
history.go(-1)
history.goBack()
```